# StructureMap Exception Code: 202 No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler, System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0

Tags: c#, wcf, structuremap

I have a WCF application where it is listening for a message.  The EventHandler uses the ServiceClient which uses HttpClient to call another API.

The IoC class:

```
public static class IoC
{
    public static IContainer Initialize()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            // Handlers
            x.For<IHandle>().Use<EventHandler>();

            // Service Clients
            x.For<HttpClient>().Use<HttpClient>();
            x.For<IServiceClient>().Use<ServiceClient>();
        });

        return ObjectFactory.Container;
    }
}
```

I tried adding this after the Initialize but before the return:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
{
    x.Scan(scan =>
    {
        scan.LookForRegistries();
        scan.Assembly("System.Net.Http");
    });
});
```

But, I still get the exception in the title.

Comment: maybe you already loaded that assembly?  https://erictummers.com/2014/05/01/no-default-instance-defined-solved-by-doing-less/

Comment: I don't think so. I added the ObjectFactory.Configure after I got the exception to try and fix it.

Comment: You are not getting an exception!!!  See following : https://restfulapi.net/http-status-202-accepted/

Comment: It is an exception. It's a StructureMap Exception Code 202, not an http status code.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue.  The problem was that I was using an older version of StructureMap (v2.6.4.1) which was not compatible with System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0.  After updating to the latest version and making some adjustments since ObjectFactory doesn't exist in the latest version, I was getting an error:

***No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler'***

This is because StructureMap defaultly tries to use the greediest constructor.  To fix this, I changed my DI for HttpClient to this:

```
x.For<HttpClient>().Use<HttpClient>().SelectConstructor(() => new HttpClient());
```